# Recursive Sequence of Bernoulli Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics

**Question**: Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be an iid sequence from a Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution. Consider the function $\Phi : \{0,1 \} \times \{0,1\} \to \{0,1\} : (u,v) \mapsto \mathbb{1}[u=v=1]$, to be zero unless $u=v=1$; i.e. $\mathbb{1}$ is the usual indicator function. Define $Y_i := \Phi(X_i,X_{i+1})= \mathbb{1}[X_i = X_{i+1}=1]$. Determine

(a) $E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \right]$

(b) $Var[ \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i]$, and

(c) let $p_n = P(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i =0)$. Find initial conditions and a recursion so that the sequence $(p_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is uniquely determined.

**My Work**: (a) is pretty straightforward. $E[Y_i] = E[ \mathbb{1}[X_i =X_{i+1} =1]]= P(X_i = X_{i+1}=1) = p^2$. So by linearity we get $np^2$.

For (b) I looked at the covariance and split this into $\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(Y_i) + 2 \sum_{1 \le i < j < n} \text{Cov}(Y_i, Y_j)$.

$$
Var(Y_i) = E[Y_i^2] - E[Y_i]^2 = E[Y_i] - E[Y_i]^2 = p^2(1-p^2).
$$

The covariance term in the summand is zero unless $j=i+1$. 
$$
\text{Cov}(Y_i,Y_{i+1}) = E[ Y_i \cdot Y_{i+1}] - E[Y_i] \cdot E[Y_{i+1}] = P(X_i = X_{i+1}=X_{i+2}=1) - p^4 = p^3-p^4
$$
There are $n-1$ instances of $j=i+1$, so part (b) equals $np^2(1-p^2)  +2(n-1)(p^3-p^4)$.

Part (c) is the main reason I ask this question . . .

We quickly find find $p_1 = 1- P(X_1=X_2=1) = 1-p^2$. For $n \ge 2$,

$$p_n=P(Y_1=\cdots=Y_n=0) = p_{n-1} \cdot P(Y_n=0 \mid p_{n-1}) = p_{n-1} \cdot P(\mathbb{1}[X_i=X_{i+1}=1]=0 \mid p_{n-1})$$

Now $P(\mathbb{1}[X_i=X_{i+1}=1]=0) = \begin{cases}
1 & X_i =0 \\
1-p & X_i = 1.
\end{cases}$

So define $g_i = \begin{cases}
1 & X_i =0 \\
1-p & X_i = 1.
\end{cases}$ Then $p_{n} = g_n p_{n-1}$.

Does this seem like an appropriate solution? I don't know if I answered the question correctly or if I seem to have misinterpreted what it's asking. The problem is from an old test, so I can't exactly check with anyone. Also curious if there's a quicker way for (b).